# No rule to make target

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to follow this tutorial:
http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/

When I am at the last makefile (#5), the "make" can't proceed becasue (error prompt) `No rule to make target "obj/hellomake.o", needed by "hellomake"`. This piece of code tries to compile the sources files and put libs, srcs, objs into respective folders.

```
IDIR =../include
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)

ODIR=obj
LDIR =../lib

LIBS=-lm

_DEPS = hellomake.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = hellomake.o hellofunc.o 
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))


$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

hellomake: $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

I have been staring at it for an hour already, it's not a complex piece of code but I couldn't eyeball the problem. I suspect the problem happens here:

```
$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

hellomake: $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

I just don't see anything wrong with it. Please help.

Comment: What it means is you need a target like `hellomake:`,  kind of like this `obj/hellomake.o:`. However, I'm wondering why you need all that. Here's an excerpt from a much simpler make file that builds embedded gcc objects for Informix 4GL on Linux. `GENSRC=chkaddr_test.c createICSLogFile.c print_width.c termlp.c lptmp.c \
 rpt_view.c unschd.c check_at.c setSchedPerms.c nfilter.c batchpay.c \

GENOBJ=$(GENSRC:c=o)

chkaddr_test: chkaddr_test.o chkaddr.o
 cc -Wall -Wshadow -g -o chkaddr_test chkaddr_test.c chkaddr.c
`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Their script is fine! Just do this:

1°) Create directory "include" and "src"

```
mkdir include; mkdir src
```

2°) Create an "obj" folder inside "src"

```
mkdir obj
```

3°) Your directory tree should look like this:

```
$:~/parentDir$ tree
.
├── include
│   └── hellomake.h
└── src
    ├── hellofunc.c
    ├── hellomake
    ├── hellomake.c
    ├── Makefile
    └── obj
        ├── hellofunc.o
        └── hellomake.o
```

4°) Now just use **make** command inside **src** directory.
 :D

Comment: You are the nicest guy I know in Stackoverflow, I rarely see people try to replicate the problem posted... I wish I can upvote you twice :)

So what I missed is that I forgot to put hellomake.h inside the ../include dir. Problem Fixed!

Comment: Hahaha. Thank you very much. You made my day. I am very happythat  you solved your problem :D

Comment: Helped me out too! Thanks. One question what does the last part of clean do? `*~ core $(INCDIR)/*~`

Comment: It removes files with a "~" at the end of their names. These are automatically created backup copies of documents edited in the gedit text editor. There might be other software that do the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have a source file named `hellomake.c`, make does not know how to make `obj/hellomake.o`.  You should also create the `obj` directory yourself since you do not have a command to do so in the Makefile, but its absence would not cause the error you report.

You probably know better and the explanation may be more subtle:

I suspect there is a missing TAB character at the beginning of this line:

```
$(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

Commands are introduced by TAB characters in Makefiles, not spaces. It is unfortunate, but nobody seems to want to fix this.

I remember meeting Stuart Feldman at Bell Labs in 1984: He was introduced to me as *the inventor of make*.  Before I could say anything, he promptly apologized this way: *I know, sorry about he TABs!*

Comment: Missing TAB character would give me "missing separator" error prompt. I fixed that issue from a another post here at stackoverflow. But you are partially correct, I didn't have the files in the right directories to start with.